PyQt5: QtStyleSheets not applying to widgets created in other files
I am trying to create a layout that is styled using an external CSS file, so I've embedded it into a QWidget as you can't style layouts directly.
The general QLabel identifier is correctly applied, the problem seems to come from when I give widgets an Id, as the CSS is not being applied. The ExampleLabel class is in another file and is imported to main.py. This is as minimal as I could get the problem.
The hierarchy of widgets is below.
QWidget (Central)
   
    QVBoxLayout
   
        QWidget (I want to style this)                                       
   
             QVBoxLayout                                                         
   
                  QLabel

Main.py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 200)
            self.setStyleSheet(open("style.css").read())

            self.central_widget = QWidget()
            self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

            self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
            self.central_widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

            self.label = item.ExampleLabel()
            self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

item.py
class ExampleLabel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setObjectName("example")

        self.label = QLabel("Hello World")

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

style.css
QLabel {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

QWidget#example {
    background-color: grey;
}



QWidget subclasses do not directly support style sheets, either use setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground) or override paintEvent().
